# Facebook Flow ignoring `index.js.flow` from linked module

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a react-native project with `stuff` as a dependency, and it's linked. It has a `dist/index.js.flow` file.

I modified the file breaking some definitions but `yarn flow` still says everything is ok. So I *deleted* the file, and it's still ok.
Eventually I *deleted* the symbolic link (it won't run) and Flow *still* says:

```
No errors!
✨  Done in 0.26s.
```

At this point I'm quite perplexed: this morning I was forced to write those definitions file and now looks like it is being ignored.